# HP ZBOOK 17 G4, MO LA-E171P BIOS locked

Tags: bios, g4

Programmed BIOS chip with a chip purchased from eBay (didn't solder to the board, but using the ch341 programmer) Copied the bios file from the eBay chip to the on board chip, the first respond with a high speed fan, no display.

Again I programmed the chip with back up file, this time nothing, only 7 blinks. Tried both BIOS many times after that but the result same, only blinks.

I don't understand it is a BIOS issues or is there anything wrong happened to the hardware when I assembled the system back.

Answer (score 1):

The
[Blinking Light Codes; Post Error Messages - HP ZBook Studio x360](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1408651/Hp-Zbook-Studio-X360-G5.html?page=97)
says:

> Caps/num lock lights 7 blinks : Sure Start unable to find valid BIOS Boot Block image

Although this manual is for another model than yours, I believe,
especially given the history of your computer, that this is exactly
your case, that the BIOS was broken by the programming.

Given that most BIOS are digitally signed by the certificate of the
manufacturer, if this is the case for your model then the answer
is that the BIOS is broken. It's likely not a hardware failure.